# Facebook integration -ios+ Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am creating app with Facebook integration. It is working fine. There is no issues. My real problem is once i close the Xcode and reopen i am not able to build my app. It showing the error
 `" No such module 'FBSDKLoginKit'"`.

Once i delete 
`FBSDKShareKit.framework`,

`FBSDKMessengerShareKit.framework`,

`FBSDKLoginKit.framework`,

`FBSDKCoreKit.framework`

these framework files add add them again application working again i am able to build and run.

What i am doing wrong? Can anyone help me to find out.
I am using `Xcode7.0.1`, `swift 2`

Comment: Actually  you have deleted but you didn't remove reference . once remove reference and add again

Comment: No it is not working i tried now,

Answer (score 0):

This is a very annoying problem.

1. Go into to your Project target, and select 'Build phases'
2. Select the dropdown that says 'Copy Bundle Resources'
3. Select the Facebook frameworks and press the '-' button at the button
4. Find the frameworks in their folder and re-drag them into the 'Copy Bundle resources' section

Hopefully that should fix your problem

Comment: Framework not available under 'Copy Bundle Resources'. It is under Link binary with Libraries. I tried your steps from there still same issue.

Comment: Of course, sorry meant 'Link binary with Libraries'. Try the same steps with that instead

Answer (score 0):

Best way can use cocoapods

pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'

or if you don't want to use pods, while adding the framework, [image: make sure 'copy items if needed is ticked, and target also]

make sure 'copy items if needed is ticked, and target also